# dynamically add textbox on button click

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I'm working with windows form application in vb.net windows form application in that there are two buttons:

1. Add new Textbox
2. Insert multiple textbox data into database

When I click on 1st button it will create new textbox and if I click on 2nd button than it should insert data of multiple textboxes  in database.

Database has two fields only

1. Id primary key
2. Name

And textbox contains name.

Please suggest me the way to implement this i have no idea about this.

Comment: Is the ID field auto-incremental?

Comment: Could you use a different control other than a textbox? Maybe a `datagridview` which you can add rows to and expand dynamically much easier than a group of text boxes.

Comment: yes it's auto-increment.

Comment: Is it posiible by datagridview???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your click-event assuming the ID-field is auto-incrementing in the database:

```
dim myTxt as New TextBox
myTxt.Name = Me.Controls.Count.ToString '"random" name
myTxt.Location = New Point(10, 10) 'set the position according to your layout
myTxt.Tag = "For DB" 'something to identify it by
myTxt.Visible = True

Me.Controls.Add(myTxt) 'add it to form's control collection.
Me.Refresh             'If in panel etc. change Me with that control.
```

Then in your second click event:

```
... open database, do checks etc.

For each c As Control in Me.Controls
    If typeof c Is TextBox AndAlso c.Tag ="For DB" Then
        Dim txt As String = CType(c, TextBox).Text
        'insert txt into database
    End If
Next
```

(A data-grid can do this for you as well).

Also you can use an array to perform the creation, and you can interact with each textbox you create by its index.

```
For y As UShort = 0 To indexsize_b - 1
    For x As UShort = 0 To indexsize_a - 1
    array(x, y) = New TextBox
    array(x, y).Size = New Size(60, 20)
    array(x, y).Location = New Point(5 + 60 * x, 40 + 20 * y)
    array(x, y).Visible = True
    Me.Controls.Add(array(x, y))
    Next
Next
```

Interact via something like:

```
string s = array(a, b).text
```

Comment: Hey can u post for data-grid-view I did it but data is not inserted into database .